# Trim text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in excel sheet, with headings in 1st Row, I want to trim them as shown below

For example

CT_CD_FILTER_AMT*_Integer

```
Change to
```

CT_CD_FILTER_AMT

Each column heading is different..and number of columns also different from each file

So I want select the value of each column  and trim it until it reaches the blank cell in ( row1 only)

Pls help with code.

TIA.

Comment: Experts here may be able to suggest you proper course to be adopted, if you can edit your question to show around 4 representative data values incorporating worst case scenarios of data variation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mac1()
Dim LastCol As Integer
Sheets("MySheet").Select
LastCol = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
For Each C In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol))
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, InStr(C.Value, "") - 1)
Next C
End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub mac2()
Dim Col As Integer
Col = 1
Do While Cells(1, Col).Value <> ""
    Cells(1, Col).Value = Left(Cells(1, Col).Value, InStr(Cells(1, Col).Value, "") - 1)
    Col = Col + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I have code for trimming text and I gave a range of certain cells with the code its working, but i do not want to give a specific range instead to do  " until empty cell".                                                    For Each C In Range("B1:Z1")                                                             If InStr(C.Value, "*") > 0 Then                                                    C.Value = Left(C.Value, InStr(C.Value, "*") - 1)                               End If Next C

Comment: Check this out now.

Comment: Second one worked but it should be Cells(col).Value  not simply col, coz col declared as integer and i need to read the value of cell..So its Cells(col).Value..Anyway Thank you so much its solved now.